# gen_tcp:accept Error Listen Socket Is Closed?

Tags: sockets, tcp, erlang

Writing a very simple TCP server for starters, but for the life of me, gen_tcp:accept in my 'accept_loop' function keeps returning `{error, closed}` immediately when it's called. So far I've been able to get everything else working thus far, but this one is really stumped me. Wondering if I fell into a beginner trap.

Anyway here is the code.

```
-module(doom_server).
-behaviour(gen_server).

-export([start_link/1, handle_client/1, accept_loop/1, accept/1]).
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, terminate/2, code_change/3]).

-define(TCP_OPTIONS, ).

-record(server_state, {
        port,
        ip=any,
        timeout=10,
        lsocket=null}).

start_link(_Args) ->
    gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, _Args, []).

init(_Args) ->
    % Get configuration from doom.config and create a new server state.
    Port = proplists:get_value(port, _Args),
    BindAddress = proplists:get_value(bind_address, _Args),
    Timeout = proplists:get_value(timeout, _Args),

    case gen_tcp:listen(Port, [binary,
        {packet, 0},
        {active, false},
        {reuseaddr, true}]) of
            {ok, ListenSocket} ->

                % Construct our server state.
                NewState = #server_state {
                    lsocket = ListenSocket,
                    port = Port,
                    ip=BindAddress,
                    timeout=Timeout
                },
                {ok, accept(NewState)};
            {error, Reason} ->
                io:format("Failed: ~w~n", [Reason]),
                {stop, Reason}
    end.

handle_cast({accepted, _Pid}, State=#server_state{}) ->
    {noreply, accept(State)}.

accept_loop({Server, ListenSocket, Timeout}) ->
    case gen_tcp:accept(ListenSocket, Timeout) of
        {ok, Socket} ->
             % Let the server spawn a new process and replace this loop
            gen_server:cast(Server, {accepted, self()}),
            handle_client(Socket);
        {error, Type} ->
            io:format("Error: ~w~n", [Type])
    end.

% To be more robust we should be using spawn_link and trapping exits
accept(State = #server_state{lsocket=ListenSocket, timeout=Timeout}) ->
    proc_lib:spawn(?MODULE, accept_loop, [{self(), ListenSocket, Timeout}]),
    State.

handle_client(Socket)->
    case gen_tcp:recv(Socket, 0) of
        {ok, Data} ->
            gen_tcp:send(Socket, Data),
            handle_client(Socket);
        {error, closed} ->
            ok
    end.

% We get compile warnings from gen_server unless we define these
handle_call(_Msg, _Caller, State) -> {noreply, State}.
handle_info(_Message, Library) -> {noreply, Library}.
terminate(_Reason, _Library) -> ok.
code_change(_OldVersion, Library, _Extra) -> {ok, Library}.
```

I've ran `erlang:port_info(ListenSocket)` just after the gen_tcp:listen and inside the accept_loop. Both output the same data, and if I put `gen_tcp:accept` inside the main thread or right after the `gen_tcp:listen` it works as expected. Am I doing something wrong when I spawn a new process?

P.S I'm using this tutorial as point of reference: http://20bits.com/article/erlang-a-generalized-tcp-server

Comment: Your are probably providing a very low timeout as the accept argument.

Comment: That's not the case. http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html#accept-1 " {error, closed} if ListenSocket is closed " I thought it was the same thing at first too.

Comment: Hmm..it's been a long time for me since I used Erlang, but did you try with `{active, true} ` ?

Comment: I've tried messing around with that, but no luck. At first I thought it had to do with accept needing to be running on the same process as gen_tcp:listen, but that's not the case ether.

Comment: "The accept call does not have to be issued from the socket owner process. Using version 5.5.3 and higher of the emulator, multiple simultaneous accept calls can be issued from different processes, which allows for a pool of acceptor processes handling incoming connections." - Erlang Docs

Comment: My guess is that you're starting the `doom_server` from a process that dies while you're expecting the server to keep running, but because that process is linked to the `doom_server`, when it dies, it takes the server and listening socket down with it. Calling `accept` on a closed listening socket returns `{error,closed}`.

Comment: That sounds like it would make a lot of sense. In that case wouldn't it make much more sense to move the accept loop into the main process and calling a new process for every connection then? (Assuming this is the correct way to go about it. Obviously other tech, this sounds like blasphemy. hehe)